# Spring MVC Controller jsp file not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple demo web for training purposes. The web displays the static content index.html correctly but whenever I try to route to ***/greeting*** url (specified by my controller) I get 404 error as showed below

[image]

However My code structure is the following

[image]

And the applicaiton.properties fiels is configured:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

My controller is also defined:

```
package com.pluralsight.conference.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("greeting")
    public String greeting(Map<String,Object> model) {
        model.put("message","Hello Jonel");
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml is configured as a war and the dependencies are the following

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Jonel

Comment: Does your `ConferenceApplication`  extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`?

Comment: Yes indeed. That is why I am surprised

Answer (score 0):

To use `jsp` as your *view resolver*, you need *another embedded servlet container* for Spring Boot Starter Web. Add the following to your dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency

Comment: I finally need to change WEB-INF name to a different one!!

Comment: WEB-INF perfectly works. I tried it myself and it worked on the first try

Comment: I am using version 2.4.1 spring-boot-starter-parent. Try with that version